# meteor: database is undefined

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish

I'm having some troubles understanding, what i believe is trivial but i can't seem to get my head around it.

I have this publish function in server.js (server only)

```
    Meteor.publish("tikiMainFind", function(){

      return tikiDB.find()

    })
```

In app.js (server + client) i'm declaring this mongo collection:

```
    tikiDB = new Mongo.Collection("tiki")
```

Why is it that this doesn't work in client.js

```
console.log(tikiDB.find())

//ReferenceError: tikiDB is not defined
```

Comment: It's probably a load order issue. Try putting `app.js` under the `/lib` directory. You'll want all of your collection definitions to load first before the rest of your app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any idea how you have your app structured, I agree with David Weldon's answer.  Check [File Load Order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fileloadorder) to see what order your files are getting loaded.